# Problem with QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

Tags: qgis, api, c++

I would like to change the coordinatereferencesystem for my application

I have this code :

```
QgsMapRenderer* myRender = mapRenderer();
mQgsCoordinate = new QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(myRender->destinationCrs());
myRender->setMapUnits( QGis::Meters );
myRender->setProjectionsEnabled( true );
mQgsCoordinate->createFromOgcWmsCrs("CRS83");
qDebug() << " mQgsCoordinate = " << mQgsCoordinate->description();
if( mQgsCoordinate->isValid())
    qDebug() << "CMyQgsMapCanvas::setProjection OK";
else
    qDebug() << "CMyQgsMapCanvas::setProjection NOK";
```

I have always NOK and the mQgsCoordinate->desciption which return a QString is always Empty !!!
What's wrong ? Did I forget a step to change the CorodinateReferenceSystem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you get the identifier correct:

`mQgsCoordinate->createFromOgcWmsCrs("CRS:83");`

You get a return value directly from the createFromOgcWmsCrs method which indicates if the call was ok.

To make your development easier: it's straightforward to use the python console for finding the correct usage:

```
>>> a = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem()
>>> a.createFromOgcWmsCrs('CRS83')
False
>>> a.createFromOgcWmsCrs('CRS:83')
True
```

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the syntax and it was correct, I have made a test with "OGC:CRS83" and i have the same problem. Finally after check the code i found the problem. The problem is when i make a setExtent of the mMapCanvas.